# Error 502: Bad Gateway - Como resolver

Tags: django, http, nginx, http-status

## O que está acontecendo

A partir de ontem de manhã, em uma certa parte do site, no cadastro de usuários para ser mais exato, muitos vezes ao tentar efetuá-lo, o nginx devolve a mensagem de **502 - Bad Gateway**. O que pode gerar isso ? Nenhum código do site foi modificado nessa parte do usuário e ele começou a aparecer.

OBS: O sistema está feito em **Django**, e páginas estáticas servidas pelo **Nginx**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara, da uma estudada em status code. Parece piada mas o mínimo de conhecimento em status code vai te ajudar muito em várias coisas.
Tem muito desenvolvedor que não sabe o que é um 303, 401, 409, 502 entre vários outros.

É um conhecimento básico que todo desenvolvedor deve saber.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

502 indica que existe alguma configuração no servidor que atende a esta requisição está errada.

Comment: Você está certo certo cara, já encontrei aqui e vou estudar os erros. Obrigado !